# Spray json marshalling

Tags: json, marshalling, unmarshalling, spray, spray-json

I'm on a quest to create a JSON API where some of the models could be nicely generalized. I'm a newbie in Spray, so I started out a spike with an over simplified example.

However I can't figure out what is going on with the bellow code...

I have imported both

- my custom implicits and
- spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport._

As I understand this is what I have to do in order to have an implicit in scope that can convert from JsonFormat to Marshaller.

Compiler error:

> TestService.scala:15: could not find implicit value for parameter um: spray.httpx.unmarshalling.FromRequestUnmarshaller[my.company.Test[my.company.X]]

Code:

```
package my.company

import spray.routing.HttpService
import spray.json.{JsValue, JsObject, JsonFormat, DefaultJsonProtocol}


trait TestService extends HttpService {

  import my.company.TestImplicits._
  import spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport._

  val test =
    path("test") {
      post {
        entity(as[Test[X]]) {
          test => {
            complete(s"type: ${test.common}")
          }
        }
      }
    }
}

trait Common {
  def commonData: String
}

case class X(id: Long, commonData: String) extends Common
case class Y(commonData: String) extends Common

case class Test[T <: Common](comment: String, common: T)

object TestImplicits extends DefaultJsonProtocol {

  implicit val xFormat = jsonFormat2(X)
  implicit val yFormat = jsonFormat1(Y)

  implicit val yTestFormat: JsonFormat[Test[Y]] = new JsonFormat[Test[Y]] {
    def write(test: Test[Y]) = JsObject()
    def read(js: JsValue) = Test("test", Y("y"))
  }

  implicit val xTestFormat: JsonFormat[Test[X]] = new JsonFormat[Test[X]] {
    def write(test: Test[X]) = JsObject()
    def read(js: JsValue) = Test("test", X(1L, "y"))
  }
}
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

**SOLVED**

Solution was (as @jrudolp suggested) both to:

- Move implicit definitions on top of the file (surprising)
- Create RootJsonFormat rather than JsonFormat.

Comment: If you have everything in one file you must make sure that you either 1) define an implicit before its usage (move TestImplicits to the top) or 2) make the return type of the implicit explicit (`implicit val xFormat: RootJsonFormat[X] = ...`)